# Why are planes generally painted white?

Tags: airliner, paint, livery

When planes come off the assembly line at the factory, they're green:

[image]

So why are most painted white? Surely a darker colour would hide dirt better?

[image]

Is there a reason planes are traditionally white?

---

Here's a clip that shows a Boeing 747 being painted:

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=colorful+planes&tbm=isch - plenty of planes are not white at all.

Comment: @oakad This is the reason for the word "generally" in the title :)

Comment: It's not a primary reason, but hiding dirt is NOT what you want.  1.  It increases drag.  2.  It often indicates problems - leaking seals, internal pipe leaks, corrosion in exposed flap tracks etc.

Comment: Ok, I do not find references to underpin that statement, but a gifted car mechanic once told me, that white lacquer is *harder* than other colors. (Well, most craftsmen in Germany **have** white cars...).

Comment: The Concorde was painted with a special type of white paint because any other color would cause the airframe to heat up way beyond its design limits at Mach 2 cruise. The Pepsi Concorde was painted blue, and was hence not allowed to fly at Mach 2 for more than 20 minutes at a time: http://www.concordesst.com/history/events/pictures/pepsi6.jpg

Comment: The 747 in your second photo is an outdoor exhibit at a museum: it's not at all representative of the condition of an in-service commercial airliner.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Don't kid yourself... http://i.stack.imgur.com/xjmrM.jpg (that, just from searching for 'dirty plane')

Comment: I would be asking why Air France planes are so dirty based on your findings!

Comment: I'd say everything painted into white does reflect most light, thus protecting the object under from heating, and this applies for Airplanes, Cars, and Buildings.

Comment: Many aeroplanes used to be raw silver metal. White makes them look more modern for their owners. Silver is more efficient. Here is a boeing being repainted in time-lapse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBcjhqWigK8

Comment: @ufomorace Could you expand upon `Silver is more fficient.` Do you mean weight efficiency or reflective efficient? BTW. aesthetically, I actually like raw silver metal the best. It's my favorite color, and since it's so shiny it's kinda like 2 colors in one: white and light gray. Maybe you could add some colored streak highlights, but there's nothing wrong with silver IMO.

Comment: Hi, the trade description for a silver aeroplane is called "polished", so if you check "polished aeroplane" on google there are many very cool photos of silver aerplanes. Perhaps they have also been painted chrome. To polish aluminium i think that you need to buff it with a fluffy buffer quite often because it oxydizes and tarnishes, so it is roughly the same but slightly more expensive that paint for a fleet. here is an article on it: polished airplane by Boeing. http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/aero_05/textonly/fo01txt.html

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**White has some significant thermal advantages over color.** In most cases, this is probably just a benefit in terms of keeping the cabin slightly cooler. In the case of 'plastic' airplanes (those built with composite construction), some airframes *require* the use of white paint on upper surfaces to keep some elements within limits. [Early Diamond Aircraft designs had a 38° C](http://www.diamondaircraft.com/library/19/10/Temperature_limitation.pdf) outside air temperature limit, **past which the main spar is not considered structurally sound**.

As a result, Diamond would only manufacture aircraft with predominantly white upper surfaces, as darker surfaces could result in significant heat gain.

[image: DA-20 55C overtemp indicator]

Avweb has [an article on the DA-20](http://www.avweb.com/news/reviews/182565-1.html?redirected=1) that shows the bright red **over-temp indicator** that raises the maximum temperature to 55° C, [added as a Service Bulletin](http://www.diamondaircraft.com/library/19/10/Temperature_limitation.pdf).

Comment: I read some time ago that supersonic aircraft like Concorde also required almost all-white livery due to thermal issues

Comment: It's worth noting that I doubt this is the definitive answer, even though it's been accepted. The structural temperature issues are only really relevant for the newest composite designs. There's no place on earth that's likely to be hot enough to cause issues with an aluminum airframe.

Comment: ...except maybe a volcano.

Comment: @egid:  How about at 80,000 feet and Mach 3.2?  The SR-71 Blackbird was built out of titanium because the high temp "enjoyed" at cruise speed would melt aluminum easily.

Comment: Also, the SR-71 was black.  It was heated by friction with the atmosphere, not by solar heating.  Diamonds as noted above are white to avoid getting solar heat, the SR-71 was black to efficiently radiate the heat of friction away.

Comment: @SkipMiller I'd say it's the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: @egid:  Without question, the SR-71 is exceptional in many ways!

Answer (score 79):

The green coating is a primer (historically zinc chromate, these days zinc phosphate is used as it's less of an environmental hazard) - While you could theoretically fly around like that it is a rather ugly shade of green, so most folks (and airlines) tend to paint their aircraft some other color.

**So why white?**
White has a few advantages, but the two biggest ones I can think of are these:

- **White is a nice, neutral base color.**
  Artists typically start out with a white canvas, or white paper - it's a color associated with "blank" and "clean" (the latter moreso if you actually *wash* the aircraft, of course...). 
  Starting with a white base coat allows the airline's marketing department to paint whatever livery they want on their flying billboards.
- **White doesn't fade.**
  Or perhaps it's more accurate to say "you don't really *notice* when white fades.". 
  An average airliner will have several paint jobs during its service life, but the longer you can go between having to reprint the plane the better, and if you don't have to worry about the paint fading and looking old for a good long while you cans stretch the time between paint jobs without having your passengers start making snide comments about your fleet of flying hoopties.
  All colored paints will eventually fade from exposure to sun and the elements, particularly exposure to the sun at 30,000 feet, where substantially more UV radiation is hitting the paint and accelerating the fading process.

---

Of course there's nothing that says the base coat HAS to be white: Southwest has a very attractive blue/red/orange livery, and American Airlines has traditionally incorporated polished aluminum in their livery (which also affords a substantial weight savings, by not priming & painting the entire body of the aircraft).

[image: Current Southwest livery] [image: American Airlines old livery (MD-80)]

Comment: You say "a substantial weight savings" - Do you have a reference for how much the paint weighs for a given plane?

Comment: @RichardMiskin It obviously varies depending on how much surface needs to be covered, and to a lesser extent on the type of paint used (urethane paints are pretty much the standard in aviation these days).  [This Daily Apple article has a table from Boeing](http://dailyapple.blogspot.com/2013/04/apple-633-weight-of-airplane-paint.html), which puts the weight of a full paint scheme on a 747 at 555lbs (versus 55lbs for  polished skin & a logo).

Comment: @vortaq7 There was an article in the seat pocket magazine years ago on an American Airlines flight.  Their former livery - polished aluminum accented by a stripe of multicolored paint - saved 200 pounds.  that is from memory and applies to the MD-80 series.  So they save the weight of one passenger on each flight.  I wish I could remember the fuel savings they claimed, but it was substantial on an annual basis.

Comment: "Ugly shade of green"... you _do_ realize it's St Patricks Day, and you've just antagonized everyone of Irish descent? ;) I seem to remember a story about interned B-29s that landed in Russia during WWII due to battle damage over Japan, and the Russians copied them exactly, down to the exposed green primer in the aft portion (the factory had run out of interior white paint, or something).

Comment: @SkipMiller Unfortunately the cost savings from not painting the aircraft is more than offset by the cost to keep the aluminum polished.  :)

Comment: @RichardMiskin Check out [this YouTube clip](http://youtu.be/Lk7UFNeRDSQ) from Megafactories, with Boeing painting a new 747. This would concur with voretaq7.

Comment: @Lnafziger:  Your source for this information?  If that is true why did they do that?  Doesn't make sense!

Comment: @SkipMiller My source is [Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/aero_05/textonly/fo01txt.html) and the reason is that it ends up being a relatively small difference and is a marketing decision by the airline.

Comment: The 737-700 is 179 lbs. to paint the entire aircraft.

Comment: @Lnafziger The amount quoted for the 747 in the above clip is 500kg, so 1,100 lbs.

Comment: @DannyBeckett My number is for the 737 (which is what voretaq7 was referring to in his answer where he said "significant weight savings"), and not the 747.  According to the document that I linked to in my previous comment on Boeing's website, the 747-400 paint weighs 555 lbs (251.7 Kg), so I'm not sure where they got 500 kg.

Comment: @Lnafziger Sure, I was just pointing out that the weight savings could be even higher. I'm not sure where they got that figure from though.

Comment: +1 for `fleet of flying hoopties`!

Comment: As noted in my answer below, (though it was a while ago and I forgot to mention it here) the green shown on the first picture in original question is NOT primer, it is Temporary Protective Coating, a spray-on plastic that is chemically rinsed off during the paint process.

Answer (score 21):

Of course, in certain situations a plane *has* to be painted white...or another colour.

Concorde had to be finished in a special, [highly reflective white paint](http://www.speedbirds.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/concfacts.htm) to mitigate the extreme heating effects that friction caused at mach 2.

> [It] reaches 127° C at the nose and trailing edge, but the special ‘high-reflectivity’ white paint helps reflect and radiate heat. Its reflectivity is 80 out of 100, compared to the rating of normal white paint of 45-50 out of 100, Concorde is re-painted every three years.

Conversely, the SR-71 Blackbird was painted matte black for almost exactly the same reason, plus some radar signature reduction.

Comment: That Concorde-link gives a 403. :-(

Comment: @MartinSchröder It seems to be working now, but you can always view it at https://web.archive.org/web/20130713084122/http://www.speedbirds.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/concfacts.htm

Comment: Reflective paint makes the plane a *poor* radiator of heat.

Answer (score 20):

Two reasons for white I've been told many times are:

- white paint is cheaper than other colours (either because it costs less and/or weighs less)
- white makes it easier to apply names and logos of other companies when leasing your aircraft to someone else. Saves a trip to the paint shop, instead you just apply stickers.

Both make sense, but whether they're the main reason I don't know.

Comment: Do they _really_ use stickers for names and logos? I would think it likely they would come off too easily.

Comment: @PhilPerry yes, they do. And yes, they do sometimes come off when not properly applied. But it's quite possible to use stickers that require special chemicals to get off.

Comment: Why couldn't you place a sticker on an airplane with some other color?

Comment: @Speldosa you can. White is however nicely neutral. If you put KLM stickers on a US Airways aircraft... Now put them on an Air France aircraft... In both cases after removing the original titles and logos of course. And that's how rental/short term lease companies work.

Comment: Stickers are also used for special, non-permanent liveries, such as the Hobbit-themed liveries that Air New Zealand has had the last few years.

Comment: @reirab of course, same thing effectively as a short lease or rental. You put the styling on for a very limited time only.

Answer (score 14):

Contrary to voretaq7's highly upvoted answer, the green coating in your first image is NOT a primer. It's a spray-on plastic protective coating usually referred to as "Temporary Protective Coating (TPC)". This is used primarily as a barrier to oxidation, as there is a very thin layer of very pure aluminum on the exterior surface of the skin.

During some of the videos available of the painting process for a new aircraft, you will see them spray a chemical over the entire airplane as the first step. This chemical dissolves the TPC, and leaves a super-shiny aluminum surface for them to then proceed to paint.

The primer paint used on the exterior of the skin during the full paint process is usually a yellow color, not the traditional "Boeing green" seen on interior parts that don't get a final paint coat.

As for why white is the primary color of choice, I unfortunately do not know. However I would point out that Southwest Airlines does not use a white base-coat on their current livery (term for the paint scheme), American Airlines' new 787's are actually a very light blue, and there was the Air New Zealand black 787 shown in another answer...

Source/Disclaimer: I am employed by Boeing on the Commercial production lines.  Information I have provided  is, to the best of my knowledge, accurate and not considered proprietary.

Comment: Where is the "there" that you work?

Comment: Boeing, commercial aircraft, structures assembly

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. I hope you stick around, with that background, your knowledge will be highly prized around these parts!!

Comment: @Rayanth, that makes sense. I live very close to many boeing factories and I have noticed that the planes are yellowish-green. You are right, they do not look like boeing green, they instead look more of a yellowish green.

Answer (score 11):

White makes it easier to spot another plane in the air, since white shows up well against the ground.  This is why many early planes were colored on the bottom half and white/silver for the rest.

Of course, this matters much less with modern IFR equipment and doesn't matter really at all with high-altitude jets, but old habits die hard, I guess.

Comment: is this also the reason why military planes are not white?

Comment: @user13107 That's probably more to do with stealth/camo: [Dark spot under cockpit on A-10s](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2102)

Comment: @DannyBeckett that sounds like exactly what user13107 is talking about. :) If white makes an airplane easier to spot, camouflage (not white) would make military planes harder to spot.

Comment: I'm not so sure about white being easy to spot - at least in my personal experience. The most visible plane I've ever seen was painted an utterly hideous shade of yellow-green (about the same color they paint the ARFF trucks) - I saw that thing buzzing away in the pattern when I was about 8 miles from the airport and never lost sight of it!

Comment: @user13107 White is actually pretty hard to spot when looking up at it, particularly if there are clouds. This is why some airplanes have white tops (easier to spot with the ground as a backdrop) and dark colored bottoms which stand out from the sky.

Comment: And consider that a lot of birds and especially fish do it the other way around, lighter underneath ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, yeah, countershading is very effective. That's partly why military aircraft are often camo on top, lighter solid underneath.

Comment: I agree with @voretaq7, a shade of yellow or yellowish green would be easiest to spot. If you have ever seen a DHL plane you know what I am talking about. Those things are painted yellow AND red. I think that the reason most planes are painted white is that you can put a lot of logos on white, and that white looks cleaner than other colors.

Answer (score 11):

Another minor reason is that white color protects from adverse radiation better.

In regards to nuclear bombers this is called '[anti flash white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-flash_white)', though regular planes flying at high altitudes supposedly benefit from this as well.

Answer (score 10):

I work for a printing company.

Think of this - why everything is printed mostly in black ink? why not navy blue, or dark hunter green?

Because black is a stock color.

The manufacturer stocks it, and uses it left and right.
Most other colors have to be a special order - this comes with increased costs, lead times and paint expiration. If you did not use all of it, paint does expire.

To the printer-happy community let me remind you that painting a jet is not like printing a page where three base inks are used to create a perception of color.
Paint of any color has to be manufactured separately.

So I think that from a manufacturing standpoint it is just so much cheaper to use stock white paint.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the above reasons are valid. I worked at Eastern airlines and we switched from the white/blue livery to polished aluminum because the weight/drag reduction vs. increased manpower cost still was overall cost effective. Remember a 747 uses around 90 gallons of paint weighing in the vicinity of 550 pounds.

Comment: `I worked at Eastern airlines`, wow, that's something you just don't hear every day anymore!  My uncle worked for them until they shut down.

Comment: of course now, with aircraft ever more made of plastics and other non-metalic components, having them in bare metal requires painting them that way, which is costing American Airlines a fair bit :)

Answer (score 8):

You are all right to a point / close:

Here are the main factors in order of importance:

1. White paint is both cheap and easy to apply.
2. White paint on most of the aircraft allows for quick and easy    resale (the new airline simply puts new tail art on it).
3. White paint shows any anomalies quickly — hydraulic/fuel leaks,    dirt, damage.
4. White paint has the best thermal reflective properties for both    radiation from the sun and reflected radiation from the
   tarmac    (although in northern climates / winter this is reversed)!

People don't generally choose their airline because of it livery, they generally choose the cheapest fare. Therefore white paint is the colour of choice. It all boils down to money.

Comment: could you substantiate your claims? what makes white paint cheap/easier to apply (!) than a color paint? Also, please consider polishing language and spelling.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from technical reasons, I am not really aware of, let me put it this way: **Would you fly in a black plane?** Probably not.

You associate colours with objects, feelings, situations etc.

White can be trivially associated with sky, just like blue. I believe most airlines stick to these colours, since it helps associating the brand with sky. But the colours can have deeper meaning which is often used for marketing purposes. White is often associated with trust and perfection. Blue is associated with quality, security, trust or business. Notice many company logos are blue and white - Facebook, IBM, GE, Samsung, Hilton.

Comment: Actually this black plane looks pretty slick: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5oUfl.jpg

Comment: I must say this really surprises me and I was not aware of that.

Comment: To be fair, this has special meaning in New Zealand.  Their national rugby team is named the All-Blacks, and Air New Zealand as a part of their sponsorship of the team has adopted the black livery for a few of their planes.

Comment: Though personally, I'm quite a big fan of this black plane:  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/B-2_Spirit_original.jpg

Comment: Do you have any sources for this or is it just your personal opinion?

Comment: The reasons for the colors to be used is just my opinion, however the color associations are not made by myself, you can see for instance http://www.joehallock.com/edu/COM498/associations.html. I just corrected few inaccuracies.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple actually: White paint is both cheaper and lighter than paint with colorant added to it.  Both of these are important when trying to reduce cost at an airline!

Comment: I'm led to believe cost isn't the only reason... Something about white reflecting heat? [airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/2124715/) [answers.yahoo.com](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006010503053)

Comment: I'm not sure what the weight differential is - when I go in for my paint job I'll have to pick some brains on that. I imagine the difference isn't too substantial, but on the scale of an airliner an ounce or two per gallon would add up to quite a bit of weight :-)

Comment: @DannyBeckett, Surfaces that appear white appear so because they reflect all wavelengths of light. Surfaces that appear black appear so because they absorb all wavelengths of light. Other colors are in between. When a material absorbs light energy, it gets transferred into heat energy. I'm not sure that this is the primary reason it's commonly used on aircraft, but I'm sure it does help.

Comment: Are you sure white is lighter? Coloured paint is not white paint with a colour added: white paint is typically itself coloured with titanium dioxide.

Comment: white paint, itself, has a colorant added to it. Most truly white paints use titanium dioxide as a colorant.

Answer (score 5):

White paint won't absorb as much heat as black or another color, imagine walking on bare blacktop vs. the white painted line.  I found [this](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=3873) article to save me the explanation.  The black paint absorbs the entire spectrum of photons, whereas the white reflects most of the  photons.  When a photon is absorbed, its energy is absorbed (a photon is energy) and the heat of the plane increases.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than painted white, Boeing documents the option of keeping a fleet "polished" raw aluminium. Polished is more efficient to fly, but it requires more maintenance, buffing the entire plane multiple times a year, whereas painted aeroplanes require maintenance every 4 years... Here is an article with silver colored versus painted aeroplanes by Boeing:

[Polished vs Painted by Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/aero_05/textonly/fo01txt.html)

here are pictures of [polished aeroplanes](https://www.google.fr/search?q=polished%20airplane&num=100&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

There are various fan pages that talk about polishing planes.

Military planes are often painted different from civilian ones and with regard to camouflage, grey, cammo, blue for sea, it's mostly fleet themes and standards.

[image: jal cargo2]

Paint on a large plane adds something like 230 kilos, 475 lbs for a B777-200 airliner. Amercian airlines was the last to have silver aeroplanes: http://www.airlinepilotchatter.com/2013/01/new-american-airlines-livery-to-paint.html

Comment: Welcome. The question is: "*Why are most painted white? Surely a darker colour would hide dirt better*". Your post doesn't seem to address that.

Comment: Please read the above answers and apply the same comment to those which you feel apply, it will be many of them, as none mentions cleanliness and some mention polished being the best color for an aeroplane rather than using paint.

Answer (score 2):

As stated before,  White is cheaper.  There is no thermal benefit for subsonic planes at cruising altitudes.  Windchill and ambient temperature at flight levels are below freezing.