# Is this a Janet Airlines 737 at Area 51?

Tags: airline-operations, aircraft-identification

I was looking at the satellite image of area 51 on google earth and i noticed an airplane that was taxiing alone on area 51 at 37°14′0″N 115°48′30″W or (R-4808N) could this be a Janet airlines Boeing 737 from Las Vegas that carries the government workers to and from the base??
[image: Google Maps screenshot]

Comment: I don't think the US military routinely declassifies information on the Stackexchange network so there's probably no definite answer.

Comment: @Sanchises, nothing can be declassified on SE, because there is no classified information in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Probably yes.**

[Janet Airlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janet_(airline)#Fleet) operates the [Boeing 737-600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation#Specifications) (and some Beechcraft turboprops), which has a wingspan of $ 34.32 \, \mathrm{m} $ and a total length of $ 31.24 \, \mathrm{m} $. I measured the size of the aircraft using the Google Maps distance tool:

[image: Aircraft at Area 51]

The dimensions of $ \sim 34 \, \mathrm{m} $ span and $ \sim 30 \, \mathrm{m} $ length match (within the accuracy of the Google Maps image) the dimensions of the 737-600. The white fuselage paint also matches the Janet airlines aircraft:
[image: Janet Airlines 737-600]
(image source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:(EG_%26_G)_N288DP_Boeing_737-600_C-N_29892_(5641861676).jpg))

Most civilian aircraft are [painted white](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2354/why-are-planes-generally-painted-white) of course, but military aircraft are typically not. The red stripe is not visible from above, so it is impossible to say for sure, but since I don't expect many other white 737-600s to fly to Area 51, I think it is a fair bet to say this is indeed a Janet airlines aircraft.