# Why aren't the undersides of military aircraft painted bluey-grey to camouflage them against the sky?

Tags: military, paint

Why aren't military aircraft painted a bluey-grey colour to camouflage them against a bluey-grey sky?

(I researched this but couldn't find a clear answer)

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15495/62), possibly even a dupe

Comment: I believe that you're asking from a false premise. You might be better off asking the inverse question: Why are these specific aircraft (with images/links) _not_ painted blue-grey

Comment: Also related, though not a duplicate: [Blending in isn't always the best camouflage option](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2081/64).

Comment: The B2 stealth bomber is not only painted on the bottom to match the color of the sky it flies in, but for some missions actually adjusts its altitude to find the least visible level of lighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shades of Blue-grey you say? So.......

The F15
[image]
<sub>(source: [boeing.com](http://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/defense/f-15_strike_eagle/images/eagle_hero_lrg_01_1280x720.jpg))</sub>

The Mig21
[image]

The AWACS
[image]
<sub>(source: [airforce-technology.com](http://www.airforce-technology.com/projects/767awacs/images/767awacs3.jpg))</sub>

The Eurofighter
[image]
<sub>(source: [ausairpower.net](http://www.ausairpower.net/JOW/Typhoon-DD-RIAT-2009-JOW-1S.jpg))</sub>

To name a few I could think of from the top of my head. Almost every military aircraft has a variant that has been painted along the blue-grey spectrum at some point or another.

Comment: The next question could be why is the AWACS radar dome black with a white stripe...

Comment: Psy-ops against the population on the ground who can't see the camouflaged plane so freak out at the flying saucer. \*nodnod\*

Answer (score 3):

You probably only *think* there aren't any because the ones we see, typically, are for show. Say, for example, the blue angels, or for domestic use where camouflage isn't as important. In a foreign theater of war, the aircraft would be painted appropriately I.E. blue-gray, black (depending on the mission).